# PHP - How to extract the reponse code from nusoap response?

Tags: php, wsdl, nusoap

Here's the response from a WSDL

```
<return code='6000'></return>
```

I would like to return the code value. Can i use `simplexml_load_string()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);

$code = (int) $xml->attributes()->code;
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/szyebe).

Comment: @user1189060 Check the CodePad.

Comment: <return code="1"><confid>323563</confid></return> now how to retrieve the confid value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use DOMDocument() to get node values as well as attribute values.

```
$dom_boj=new DOMDocument(); //Creating object to the class DOMDocument()
$dom_boj->loadXML($XMLResponse); // loading your response using loadXML

//Traversing all return tags. 

foreach($dom_boj->getElementByTagName('return') as $tagName)  
{            
                 echo $tagName->getAttribute('code');   
}
```